# encodeURIComponent Not Working with Web API Call

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting a `404 Not Found` when making this call:

```
var url = rootWebApiUrl + '/folders/' + $scope.selectedServer.Name + "/" + serviceName;
$http.get(url) // the rest of this line doesn't matter for this issue
```

I thought that maybe using `encodeURIComponent` would help, but I get the same `404 Not Found` error:

```
var url = rootWebApiUrl + '/folders/' + $scope.selectedServer.Name + "/" + encodeURIComponent(serviceName);
```

This is the Web API Method Signature:

```
[Route("folders/{serverName}/{serviceName}")]
[HttpGet] 
public IEnumerable<Folder> Folders(string serverName, string serviceName)
```

The first option (above) works if I change the service name while debugging. The original service name is `Company Name Message Bus Manager 3.6 - MesFinishingEvents`. If I change it to something with no spaces, like `snuh`, then the Web API call succeeds and I can debug in the Web API method.

How can I pass the original service name in my `$http.get(url)` call?

Edit: URL values:

With service name that has spaces:
`http://localhost:4153/api/services/folders/ServerName/Company%20Name%20Message%20Bus%20Manager%203.6%20-%20MesFinishingEvents`

Using a simple service name:
`http://localhost:4153/api/services/folders/ServerName/snuh`

Comment: Have you tried this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13406807/573218

Comment: Just tried it. Same problem.

Comment: what does url look like before it's sent to the API in both scenarios?

Comment: @DavidL I added the URL values to my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebAPI controllers struggle when you have a `.` in your parameters, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11728846/3199927) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13299048/3199927).

Your method call would work all the way up to:

`http://localhost:4153/api/services/folders/ServerName/Company%20Name%20Message%20Bus%20Manager%203`

and beyond, if the period didn't exist.

The quickest solution is to add a trailing slash.  The longer solution would be to modify your sites HTTP handlers in IIS.