# 'nul' as route parameter returns 404 in ASP.NET Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

If I create a simple controller in ASP.NET Web API like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("values")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{value}")]
    public string Get(string value)
    {
        return value;
    }

}
```

Performing a get on `/values/nul` returns a 404 page on IIS and IIS express.
Also `/values/nul.be` returns 404.
A breakpoint in the controller is never hit in this case, so the request is terminated before it reaches the controller's logic.
Is there a work around for this or is this a bug in ASP.NET Web API?

Comment: Did you try just to access "/values", without "null"?

Comment: It is nul (this is not a typo!) that I mean, not null (passing null is not a problem). Just try it yourself!

Comment: Can you post the full URL of the request?

Comment: If IIS express runs on port 52158, the request would be `http://localhost:52158/values/nul`

Comment: it may be like `http://localhost:61709/api/values/nul`

Comment: Well, `http://localhost:52158/values/bla` works and any other valid url parameter does too, I know how Web API works :)

Comment: @SvenSchelfaut take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13406807/4045532

Comment: Thx @Corporalis, setting `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` to `true` solved the issue!

Comment: Why didn't you said to him: "Thank you man, can you put your comment into answer so I can accept it and help future visitors while thanking you as well in form of SO points"?

Comment: Interesting case! Looking around, this might have to do with the fact that Url's are checked with the same rules as (Windows) file paths. And `NUL` is a device file that returns no data (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#DOS.2C_TOS.2C_OS.2F2.2C_and_Windows) (also http://superuser.com/questions/317577/why-inputting-nul-in-windows-cmd-gives-a-certain-error-message). Just a guess though.