# ASP.Net Core Returning 404 when image url spaces encoded as +

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have URLs stored in a database where the spaces are encoded as `+`.
When the browser requests these urls the web server returns a 404 response.
These URLs are all for static images stored on the web server in the wwwroot folder.
If I manually change the `+` for `%20` then the image is returned correctly.

Is this a deliberate change in ASP.Net Core or is this a bug?
If it's deliberate, then it's going to be very painful for me going through the database and re-encoding all the URLs, many of which are embedded in HTML snippets (I know storing HTML in the DB or having spaces in image files aren't a good idea but it was done long before I joined the company and that's the state we're already in).

I'm using ASP.Net 2.1, running on .Net Framework.
It's running through IIS Express at the moment (during development) but will be deployed with full IIS.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783472/404-error-when-url-contains-a-for-a-parameter-with-asp-net-core) other question but it's specifically to do with API calls and the answer doesn't seem to be applicable to my question as there are no routes to change as I'm requesting static image files.

Edit: Extra detail
The html is output using `@Html.Raw(html)`
The resulting html output to the browser is of the form
`<img src="/BorderThemes/grey+4px+rounded+corners_TL.png" />`

The Html was generated on the server and then stored in the DB so we can be confident it's safe to output to the browser and, no, I have no idea why anyone would do that rather than building the HTML when it's needed but it was before my time and it's the situation I'm already in.

Update:
I've looked deeper into this and if I enter `http://localhost:8000/BorderThemes/grey+4px+rounded+corners_TL.png` into my web browser I get a page from IIS saying Http Error 404.11 saying that my URL is double encoded and linking to [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&IIS70Error=404,11,0x00000000,17134) for more information. This does include instructions on how to allow double-encoding but with warnings that it can have security consequences.
If I enter the url `http://localhost:8000/BorderThemes/grey%204px%20rounded%20corners_TL.png` I get an image back.

I was having issues with paths / html stored in the DB but after experimenting, it appears that `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode` encodes spaces as `+`. For example `WebUtility.UrlEncode("foo bar.png")` returns `foo+bar.png`, which is rejected as double-encoded by IIS.

Am I missing something or is Microsoft's function for encoding URLs encoding the URLs in a way that Microsoft's web server rejects?

Comment: Could do with a code sample before deciding if it's a bug or not; the "how" and your usage are important.  I'm more from a web forms world, but in certain places I'm used to calling the UrlEncode() function.

Comment: @Phill - I've added extra detail - there's no encoding being done when the page is generated, it was encoded previously and stored in the DB (often many years ago). I just need to output the snippets as part of the page.

Comment: You need to **prevent** the `+` signs from being generated. If your database contains these `+`s, you need to remove them. Specifically don't use **`UrlEncode()`**! To receive further help, (1) show how the `html` variable is filled, and (2) show how `html` variable is used in your Razor code.

Comment: @Peter B - My problem is that I am not encoding anything, it was encoded years ago in many cases and stored in the DB. Parsing all of the stored HTML snippets and re-encoding them is something I'd rather avoid.

Comment: Fixing it could be your only option. If data is bad, it needs to be fixed, either one time with a database script, or at every request by your C# code. Try using `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode()`, for more info see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44921258/1220550).

Comment: You need to split this problem into two parts. a) How the URL is generated? b) How the URL is resolved by the web server? Let's focus first on b). Please load the two URLs (the one you say does work and the one you say that doesn't) into a web browser directly (i.e. paste in the URL). Do either of them load? Both? Then please update your question with the working **and** non-working URLs (including http / https and the domain name). I am almost certain the URLs that you _say_ are being sent to the web server aren't the _actual_ ones being sent.

Comment: @PeterB - I'm getting the impression that I'm going to have to fix the URLs. If it was just a list of URLs that would be easy, it's just that I've got big chunks of HTML with img tags and other stuff in them, just finding the URLs is going to be difficult.
Probably an example of why you shouldn't store HTML in your DB and instead store parameters and generate it on the fly.

Comment: Once you have tested them in Chrome, then please also test them in Postman. Do you get the same results there?

Comment: Any luck with those URLs?

Answer (score 1):

If you want `%20` instead of `+` tryusing `EscapeDataString` to encode URI :

```
Uri.EscapeDataString(someString);
```

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50682381/704008

But you have already generated url & can'e do anything now so try using HtmlDecode like

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode.HtmlDecode(html);
```

I am not sure it best to use with `Raw` or some method exists like `decode` in `@Html` but try using :

```
@Html.Raw(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(html))
```

Refer: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility?view=netstandard-2.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urldecode?view=netstandard-2.0#System_Net_WebUtility_UrlDecode_System_String_