# WebAPI parameter with trailing space not propagated to endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

With a routing and controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/test/{term}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string term)
{
}
```

I want the request to `api/test/1%20` (UrlEncoded `"1 "`) be populated to the `term` parameter as a `"1 "` value. I've enabled the `<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />` in `system.web` section of web.config so the requests are coming through, however, the trailing space is removed.

The endpoint is used for some sort of suggestion functionality therefore values `"1"` and `"1 "` returns different results.

All discussions about potential solution I was able to find are talking more about howto accept such request:

[WebAPI route 404's when there is a trailing space in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406265/webapi-route-404s-when-there-is-a-trailing-space-in-the-url)

[Allowing reserved filenames in URLs](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx/)

Comment: You can add a trailing slash to force it to pass trailing space. http://example.com/api/1%20/

Comment: yep, that works @Hakunamatata, thanks for the advice. I realized I need to support also terms like `"11/"`which then breaks the routing so I ended up taking the `term` parametr from query string.

Answer (score 0):

The tip shared by Hakunamatata to add a trailing slash works for terms like `"1 "` however still doesn't support strings containg slash characters which I needed to support as well. I ended up taking `term` parameter from query string.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/test")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string term)
{
}
```

supporting request format `api/test?term=TERM` i.e. `api/test?term=1%20%2f`